# A way to swap two references in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

this is really about a bad idea of swapping two references. The references are not supposed to be resetable so it is not supposed to be possible. That much i know.

What i want to do, is to swap two references, in a way one would swap two pointers: **the addresses are swapped** but **not the data**. Assume:

```
int a = 0, b = 1;
int *pA = &a, *pB = &b;
std::swap(pA, pB);
```

Now *pA is 1 and *pB is 0, but a is still 0 and b is still 1. This is, however, impossible with references:

```
int a = 0, b = 1;
int &rA = a, &rB = b;
std::swap(pA, pB);
```

Now the references are swapped, but the original values are swapped as well. The only thing i can think of is this:

```
template <class _Ty>
struct resetable_ref {
    _Ty &ref;

    inline resetable_ref(resetable_ref &r)
        :ref(r.ref)
    {}

    inline resetable_ref(_Ty &_ref)
        :ref(_ref)
    {}

    inline resetable_ref &operator =(resetable_ref &r)
    {
        if(sizeof(resetable_ref) == sizeof(void*)) // compile-time constant (true)
            *reinterpret_cast<void**>(this) = *reinterpret_cast<void**>(&r);
        else
            memcpy(this, &r, sizeof(resetable_ref)); // optimized away as dead code
        return *this;
    }

    inline operator _Ty &()
    {
        return ref;
    }
};

int a = 0, b = 1;
resetable_ref<int> rrA(a), rrB(b);
std::swap(rrA, rrB);
```

Now a is still 0 and b is still 1, and the references inside rrA and rrB are swapped. Pity that it doesn't work without the rather ugly operator =(). At least it works for me in MSVC, not sure if g++ will accept it (but i imagine it should).

The whole reference swap is supposed to be used in an object which is constructed with a reference to another object inside, and i'd like to make a swap() function on them. I'd like to avoid using pointers because of the nice non-nullarity feature of the references. It would also be a nicer design (except for the resetable_ref itself).

Does anyone has a better idea of how to go about it? Can anyone think of some compatibility / undefined behavior issues one could run into with this?

I wrote most of the code without compiling, please bear with me if you notice some typo.

**EDIT**: It seems to me that a lot of people is missing the point of the question. I know how to use pointers, or even how to wrap pointers in a nice template. The question is tagged "*hack*" and that is what is expected. Don't tell me stuff like "don't do it, use pointer" since that is not what i asked. If you don't like the topic, don't answer, but don't downvote the question just because you would use pointer.

Comment: I suppose `std::reference_wrapper` could work. Never really used it, though.

Comment: Why don't you use a pointer rather than a reference inside your class, make it private, and then provide suitable member functions to act as accessors to the underlying `int`?  That way, you can avoid all the nasty reinterpret_cast/potential-undefined-behaviour issues.

Comment: @chris thanks, i had no idea that existed

Comment: @OliCharlesworth because i want to use reference. i know i can use a pointer, i asked about a solution of using reference in this situation, you missed the point of the question

Comment: @theswine: Presumably you're trying to solve some top-level problem (e.g. "how can I swap two objects using by-value-like semantics?", not "how can I swap references?").  If not, why are you trying to solve a low-level problem to which there's already a canonical answer ("references are not re-seatable!").  To try to "solve" that problem is to try to defeat the idioms of the C++ language...

Comment: References are meant to immutable in C++. When a reference is created, it must reference something. For the lifetime of the reference, it cannot be changed to reference something else. Doing so completely defeats the point of why references were introduced in C++.

Just use pointers to achieve what you want. That is what every other programmer in the world would do.

Comment: Use pointers. The compiler might assume that references never change  and optimize them away. Then it will crash trying to swap something that does not exist anymore

Comment: @BeniBela good point. if you can provide a minimal working example, i will accept it as an answer

Comment: If you want `nonnull_pointer<T>`, write `nonnull_pointer<T>` and don't call it `resetable_reference<T>`.

Comment: @EricUrban and that is what i did in my production code. but should it stop me wondering about it? don't think so, still think it is a good question, from theoretical point of view ...

Comment: @theswine Yes, it should stop you from wondering about it. References are not meant to be mutable. Even if you succeed in creating something like a mutable reference, you've just created awful code.

Comment: Stop writing horrible UB and just use `std::reference_wrapper`. It's a class with reference-like but reseatable semantics. Bingo.

Answer (score 3):

A mutable reference is ... no more tha a pointer, for which you need implicit dereferencing like reference have.

```
template<class T>
class mutable_ref
{
public:
    mutable_ref(T& t) :p(&t)
    {}

    operator T&() { return *p; }
    operator const T&() const { return *p; }

    void swap(mutable_ref& s)
    { std::swap(p,s.p); }

private:
    T* p;
};

// just in case you also want to specialize std::swap for mutable_ref.
// not necessary, since the generic std::swap<T> use twice =, that is available.
namespace std
{
    template<class T>
    void swap(mutable_ref<T>& a, mutable_ref<T>& b)
    { a.swap(b); }
}
```

Note the absence of a default ctor, with an initializing ctor taking a reference, that makes this class not-nullable.

The only problem is that, to access eventual T members, being the "." operator, not overridable, you need something elese for that purpose.

The simple thing is use * and -> as...

```
T* operator->() const { return p; }
T& operator*() const { return *p; }
```

to be defined inside `mutable_ref` declaration-

Comment: Oh yeah, i know C++, i know this can be done. The question was specifically how to swap references. Thanks for your reply, it's nice code.

Comment: The problem is that ... it cannot be done. That's why I posted an "imperfect workaround", that merely defines a "mutable_reference", not present in the C++ core language.

Comment: I think it is present, though: the stdlib is part of the "core language", and the stdlib contains `std::reference_wrapper`. As you implied, due to the lack of an `operator.`, right now the user must write `refwrap.get().member` - but hopefully Bjarne and co will get `operator.` into the language next time around ;-)

Comment: Yes, although `std::reference_wrapper` is more than just a reference (is a function call redirector).  `operator.` is about C++20. Right now it has two variant proposal... it will be interesting to see how it will go.