# This feels like a bit of an anti-pattern, is there a better way (C++ - assigning to references)

Tags: c++

Code:

```
static Layout::Pad& chooseFirst(Layout::Pad& A, Layout::Pad& B, bool swap) {
    if(swap) { return B; } else { return A; }
}

static Layout::Pad& chooseSecond(Layout::Pad& A, Layout::Pad& B, bool swap) {
    if(swap) { return A; } else { return B; }
}

void FlowchartDrawArea::addEdge(Layout::Pad& A, Layout::Pad& B) {
    bool swap = false;
    if(A.getPadDir() == Layout::PAD_DIRECTION::IN) {
        swap = true;
    }
    Layout::Pad& source = chooseFirst(A,B,swap);
    Layout::Pad& dest = chooseSecond(A,B,swap);

    flowchart.addEdge(new Edge(source,dest));
}
```

I don't know what else to say, static functions don't feel like the solution, but this is the problem.

Comment: Does `Edge::Edge` really take two non-const references?

Comment: @Zeta no, but I cut out a block of code between source and dest being assigned to and the add edge, otherwise someone would be like "you never even use the variables"

Comment: possible duplicate of [A way to swap two references in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463321/a-way-to-swap-two-references-in-c)

Comment: It seems overly verbose and confusing to me. I would just say `Layout::Pad& source = swap ? B : A;` and so on. Having a function called `returnFirst` that can return the second argument is just silly.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know, that's why I asked the question! See Henrik's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Layout::Pad& source = swap ? B : A;
Layout::Pad& dest = swap ? A : B;

flowchart.addEdge(new Edge(source,dest));
```

Comment: Change to: `  Layout::Pad& source = swap ? B : A;
  Layout::Pad& dest = swap ? A : B;` and you get a tick

Comment: What, a ternary expression?! Begone with your unreadable obfuscated ideas. Jk, +1.

Comment: @luk32 I feel the same way! This is the first time I've actually seen a use case for one, I shall link back to this answer in the future, and I have learnt my lesson (looking silly by not using them) from this.

Answer (score 9):

How about this:

```
if(A.getPadDir() == Layout::PAD_DIRECTION::IN) {
    flowchart.addEdge(new Edge(B,A));
} else {
    flowchart.addEdge(new Edge(A,B));
}
```

Comment: Assuming that is the only spot where those functions are used, this is clean. +1

Comment: No because I omitted a block of code that works with source and dest

Comment: @AlecTeal you should post all the relevant code though

Comment: @MarcoA. I really shouldn't, this isn't about what you guys would put in a function, or how I've designed my classes, Henrik answered my question, job done!

Comment: -1 by me then, this website isn't for randomly guessing your issues. Plus asking "is there a better way?" doesn't make sense with "this isn't about how I designed my classes"

Comment: @MarcoA. I do say that the static functions feel like an anti-pattern

Comment: so you **do** want a suggestion on the design :]

Comment: @MarcoA. I think creating static functions to assign to a reference is the wrong way, this is actually a great use for the `? :` function, see Henrik's answer and give him an upvote please.

Comment: Ok, if you need those variables for something else, other than the shown code, then Henrik's solution is better for that case. I've upvoted him :)

Answer (score 5):

Re-seating is actually where pointers shine, in general, although you can manage to confuse people by using `std::reference_wrapper<T>` if you really wish to avoid them.

```
void FlowchartDrawArea::addEdge(Layout::Pad& A, Layout::Pad& B) {
    Layout::Pad* source = &A;
    Layout::Pad* dest = &B;

    if(A.getPadDir() == Layout::PAD_DIRECTION::IN) {
        std::swap(source, dest);
    }

    flowchart.addEdge(new Edge(*source, *dest));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use it on more than one type, I would use a small templated function like:

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<T,T> swap_if(T t1, T t2, bool swap)
{
    return swap 
        ? std::make_pair(t2, t1) 
        : std::make_pair(t1, t2);
}
```

Could be easily used like:

```
std::string first{"first"};
std::string second{"second"};    
auto swapped = swap_if(first, second, true);

std::cout << swapped.first << ", " << swapped.second << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
second, first
```

Otherwise, a simple thing like that would be enough:

```
auto swapped = swap ? std::make_pair(edge2, edge1)  : std::make_pair(edge1, edge2);
```

Comment: OOOOOOVER KILL kill kill (Think UT announcer voice)

Comment: @AlecTeal Less than 2 functions, and I rather do that than 2 ifs for the same test

Comment: Upvote for effort, but it does feel like those contrived C++11 bragging snippits, Please given an upvote to the answer with a tick, because ... I feel silly for not thinking of it